# Spring Security: allow unauthenticated access to secured resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

How to configure Spring Security so that it is possible to access some resource for both unauthenticated and authenticated users? In the case the user is authenticated it must be possible to get the authentication context in the resource handling method.

No anonymous authentication must be used because we must distinguish unauthenticated (401 Unauthorized (unlucky HTTP naming)) and unauthorized (403 Forbidden) for other resources.

If we add resource to `web.ignoring()` then authentication context is not available even for authenticated users.

If the resource is not in `web.ignoring()` then for unauthenticated users Spring returns HTTP 401.

Comment: The problem this question is about has been caused by internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

in your spring security configuration file you should have something like this or equivalent...

```
<http use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_CUST_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/app2/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>
```

If you add permitAll it will allow users to view the resource...

```
<http use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="permitAll" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've probably found the problem and probably anonumous authentication will be possible. The problem seems to be with our custom `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that respons 403 instead of 401 for anonymous. Sorry for the invalid question.

Comment: You may think about deleting this question as it is invalid and has no answer, forever remaining as an unanswered question.

Comment: I can't deleted it so I've flagged it to be closed.